# OpenCV C++ DescriptorMatcher::knnMatch - significant performance difference on Windows (MSVC) vs Linux (CLANG)

Tags: c++, linux, performance, opencv, ubuntu

I am performing feature matching process using OpenCV - 4.5.3 (in C++).
I ran into an issue that performance of Matching on Windows is even 30 times slower than on Linux (Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL 2 to be precise) and depends on the number of images used for the process (more on that later).

The code which is the source of the problem looks more or less like this:

```
void matchDescriptorsPair(cv::Mat *queryDescriptors, cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> trainedMatcher)
{
    constexpr int N_NEAREST_NEIGHBORS = 2;

    vector<vector<cv::DMatch>> matches;
    matches.reserve(queryDescriptors->rows);

    trainedMatcher->knnMatch(*queryDescriptors, matches, N_NEAREST_NEIGHBORS);
    (...)
}
```

To benchmark the problem, I used a dataset containing up to 200 images with 18 MP resolution. I batched them into groups of {5, 20, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200} images and executed the same code, on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04 (WSL2).

The results can be seen on the chart below. You can see there that matching of single pairs on Linux always lasts around 2 seconds, when on Windows 10 execution time depends on the number of images in the dataset.

What can be a reason for such significant performance difference?

[image]

[Notes]

- Feature Extraction is run before, and all the features are stored in RAM (a lot of data but there is lots of RAM available inside machine)
- Matching is run in parallel (36 threads in this example - changing number of threads for Windows did not improve matching time)
- Same behavior on both Windows 10 and 11

[EDIT 1]
For Windows code is compiled using MSVC. Linux uses CLANG. I will try to build on Windows using CLANG and give you update.

Comment: Step 0 when benchmarking is to ensure that you are compiling the code with compiler optimizations enabled (usually *not* the default).

Comment: This one has been covered and some optimizations are implemented. Do you recommend any particular optimization?

Comment: Not recommending anything specific (beyond the basics of *turning on* the optimizer) - although also turning on LTO (Link Time Optimization) usually also often helps. Just wanted to point out that enabling optimization is important - many new people forget that and assume that compilers do that by default.

Comment: you benchmarked a virtual machine. this isn't a fair comparison. likely this isn't just "compiler optimizations" but the hardware capabilities that OpenCV does not see from within the VM. -- what makes you think you can run 36 threads without oversubscribing the CPU? -- you haven't provided a [mre]. your code might simply have **not done anything** and finished quickly because of that. -- please also take the [tour] and perhaps review [ask]

Comment: I can run 36 threads as this is the maximum capability of the Intel i9 processor which I am using for this benchmark. I also did a benchmark where I was changing number of maximum threads to complete the process and 36 was the best number.

Comment: The performance of the program on a pure Linux machine was also similar. (30x faster than Windows) 

The problem with minimal reproducible example is that to run feature matching, one first need to run feature extraction. The code for this is very complex and therefore I didn't want to post it there. Example: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d6f/tutorial_feature_flann_matcher.html